# Structuring my flask application in self contained folders

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have an app i am making and i would like to hold all python code, css and js assets inside a folder and name it appropriately so that one person can do a complete module,test it and upload it to the main project.

I am planning to have something like this structure

```
index.py

global_assets
global_classes
global_html_components
home(assets(js,css,images),home.html,home_widget_1.html,home_widget_2.html,home_widget_3.html,controller.py,model.py)
services
products
dashboard
```

I have this script.py

```
from flask import *  
app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/user/<uname>')  
def message(uname):  
      return render_template('message.html',name=uname)  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
   app.run(debug = True)
```

and message.html

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Message</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<h1>hi, {{ name }}</h1>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I want my app to have one entry at index.py such that i can visit urls of any of my modules and the page displays for instance in the code above

`http://localhost:5000/home/user/admin` where home is one of the folders i named above.

Is this kind of structure possible in flask?

Comment: IIUC, you're looking for [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/blueprints/). However, you would typically have more than 1 folder associated with a blueprint - you'd have a `templates` subdirectory called `home`, and routes/models/forms would be in the original folder you described. You'd also probably want separate subdirectories for js/css (if your site doesn't cover these requirements generally). See the [Python Community Page](https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site) for an example, where each primary page is its own directory.

Comment: Then you set your `url_prefix` to home when you import the blueprint into the main app. That's probably a lot more sustainable than trying to get everything completely contained in a single directory

Comment: @roganjosh    the first option for sopython wont work for me. What i am looking for is everything contained in its own folder.  have you tried flask with wsgi?

Comment: No, I haven't. I just use gunicorn which is a single command line for production

Comment: @roganjosh actually the blueprint idea is pretty good.  I found a related question for someone thinking in the same lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994325/how-to-divide-flask-app-into-multiple-py-files   I found the only way to do what i wanted is to use cgi as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664634/running-python-scripts-like-php

Comment: I'm not so sure about the 2nd link, not sure I can comment. But it looks like I might have pushed you in the right direction, so hopefully you'll be able to post your own answer if nobody can help you before that :) Good luck mate.